# xpath expression not working

Tags: html, r, xpath

```
    <DOC NUMBER=1>
<DOCFULL> -->
<br><div class="c0">
<p class="c1"><span class="c2">Dokument 1 von 3</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c0">
<br><p class="c1"><span class="c2">Associated Press Financial Wire</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c3">
<p class="c1"><span class="c2">April 25, 2012 Wednesday 9:18 PM GMT </span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c6">Apple CEO Tim Cook emerges from Steve Jobs' shadow</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">BYLINE: </span><span class="c2">By PETER SVENSSON, AP Technology Writer</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">SECTION: </span><span class="c2">BUSINESS NEWS</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">LENGTH: </span><span class="c2">794 words</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">DATELINE: </span><span class="c2">NEW YORK </span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c8"><span class="c2"> MAIN TEXT 1</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">LOAD-DATE: </span><span class="c2">April 26, 2012</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">LANGUAGE: </span><span class="c2">ENGLISH</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c4">
<p class="c5"><span class="c7">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </span><span class="c2">Newswire</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c0">
<br><p class="c1"><span class="c2">Copyright 2012 Associated Press<br>All Rights Reserved</span></p>
</div>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
```

I am new to xpath and I want to use it in combination with R (Duncan Lang's xml package) to query a html document that I received from LexisNexis. The document contains multiple news articles and each article is bounded by the `<DOC NUMBER=1> <DOCFULL>` tags. I wish to extract a couple of information for each document, e.g. to extract the SECTION information, I got this far:

```
doc <- htmlParse("hmtldoc.HTML")
xpathSApply(doc,"//span[text()='SECTION: ']/..", xmlValue)
```

which gives me:

```
[1] "SECTION: BUSINESS NEWS" "SECTION: BUSINESS NEWS" "SECTION: BUSINESS NEWS"
```

That is output I can work with. The main problem is that not every article has SECTION information. What I need to know is which article provides this information and which don't, preferably by returning NA or an empty list element so I can deduce this information myself.

Associated with this question: I tried to come up with a solution where I selected either the DOC or DOCFULL node first and went on from there, e.g.:

```
xpathSApply(doc,"//DOCFULL/*/span[text()='SECTION: ']/..", xmlValue)
```

I thought this should return the same text as above, but it doesn't. Anyways, I am still very new to this language and appreciate any help.

Comment: There are two problems with this question: 1. The XML document is severely malformed -- every compliant XML parser raises an error on it. 2. You don't specify which exactly nodes you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is more than one 'level' of descendant element between `DOCFULL` and the `span`s, you will need to either

*Be vague*

```
//DOCFULL//*/span[text()='SECTION: ']/..
```

Or
*Be Specific about the levels (div and p)*

```
//DOCFULL/*/*/span[text()='SECTION: ']/..
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used your path, but still it returns an empty list. I think it has something to do with the DOC and DOCFULL nodes. For example, `xpathSApply(doc,"//DOC",xmlAttrs)` wont return NUMBER. So I think there must be an error with the parsing process.

Answer (score 0):

With the document given, you could just use this:

```
//*[span='SECTION: ']
```

You don't need to specify find a span node with the text 'SECTION: ' and then select it's parent, you just need to select any node that has a 'span' child with that text.

If you need it to be a descendent of a `DOCFULL` element, then use

```
//DOCFULL//*[span='SECTION: ']
```