# Locating LexisNexis metadata with xpath in R

Tags: html, regex, xml, r, xpath

I'm not very experienced navigating xml/html with xpath or regex, and have a set of html-documents from LexisNexis in the following format:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <STYLE TYPE="text/css"><!--
        .c0 { text-align: center; }
        .c1 { text-align: center; margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
        .c2 { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .c3 { text-align: center; margin-left: 13%; margin-right: 13%; }
        .c4 { text-align: left; }
        .c5 { text-align: left; margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
        .c6 { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 14pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .c7 { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .c8 { text-align: left; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
        .c9 { page-break-before: always; }
        .c10 { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .c11 { border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: auto; width:100%; }
        .c12 { width: 480pt; }
        .c13 { text-align: left; padding-left: 2pt; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 2pt; }
        .c14 { font-family: 'Courier New',Courier; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .c15 { width: 120pt; }
        .c16 { text-align: right; padding-left: 2pt; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 2pt; }
        .c17 { text-align: right; margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
        .c18 { text-align: center; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; }
        .c19 { margin-left: 30pt; margin-right: 0pt; margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; list-style: none; }
        .c20 { margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt; }
        .c21 { margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; }
        .c22 { text-align: left; margin-left: 30pt; margin-top: -12pt; }
        --></STYLE>
        <!-- LXNComment 2826:543743167 -->
        <TITLE>&nbsp;</TITLE>
        <META TOPIC="null" DOCUMENTS="500" UPDATED="Tuesday, January 05, 2016  18:08:34 EST" /></HEAD>
        <BODY>
<A NAME="DOC_ID_0_0"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
<DOC NUMBER=1>
    <DOCFULL> -->
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">1 of 1301 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Lincoln Journal Star (Nebraska)</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c3"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">August 2, 2001 Thursday</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;<BR>City Edition</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c6">Class counts, not race</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">BYLINE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">BUTCH MABIN, Lincoln Journal Star</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">SECTION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">A; Pg. 1</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LENGTH: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">1779 words</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">DATELINE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Lincoln, NE </SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c8"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Study says geography plays role </SPAN></P>
            <P CLASS="c8"><SPAN CLASS="c2">  The battle lines dividing both sides of the death penalty debate came into sharp focus with Wednesday's release of a comprehensive study examining the fairness of capital punishment in Nebraska. (cut out the remaining body of text)</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">August 11, 2005</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">GRAPHIC: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">A divided time: The Sept. 2, 1994, execution of Harold Otey (above and below) drew more than 1,000 spectators to the Nebraska State Penitentiary - many of them with sharply opposing views of capital punishments. JOURNAL STAR FILE PHOTOS (one photo archived) 3 b/w head photos of Harold Otey, John Joubert and Robert Williams. (photo of Williams not archived)</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2001 Lincoln Journal Star,<BR>All Rights Reserved</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
<DIV CLASS="c9">&nbsp;</DIV>
<A NAME="DOC_ID_0_1"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
<DOC NUMBER=2>
    <DOCFULL> -->
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">2 of 1301 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Lincoln Journal Star (Nebraska)</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c3"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">February 8, 2004 Sunday</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;<BR>City Edition</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c6">Death penalty at crossroads</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">BYLINE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">JOE DUGGAN, LINCOLN JOURNAL STAR</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">SECTION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">A; Pg. 1</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LENGTH: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">2493 words</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">DATELINE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">LINCOLN, NE </SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c8"><SPAN CLASS="c2">A legislative bill on lethal injection, U.S. Supreme Court caseand constitutional appeals may affect the future of Nebraska's seven death-row inmates. (cut out the remaining body of text)</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">July 13, 2007</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">GRAPHIC: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">1. Nebraska is the only state in the nation to have the electric chair as the sole means of execution, and some wonder whether the law would survive an Eighth Amendment challenge that it is cruel and unusual punishment. 2. Seven inmates are in death row at the Nebraska State Correctional Institution in Tecumseh. 3. Marylyn Felion's portrait of Robert E. Williams, who was executed in 1997. 7 color head photos and statistics of Carey Dean Moore, Charles Jess Palmer, Michael Ryan, John Lotter, David Dunster, Raymond Mata Jr. and Arthur Lee Gales. color head photo of Summerlin JOURNAL STAR FILE PHOTO</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c5"><SPAN CLASS="c7">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
        <BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2004 Lincoln Journal Star,<BR>All Rights Reserved</SPAN></P>
        </DIV>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
</BODY></HTML>
```

Now, I would like to extract the dates for each document, and tried following the guidelines offered in [this now closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713222/xpath-expression-not-working). But, the suggestions seem to rely on tags (like "SECTION:"), which I only have for the "LOAD-DATE: " (not always the same as the actual date above the headline). Even so, attempting the suggested expressions, like below seem to give no results:

```
> ex <- htmlTreeParse("~/Desktop/example.html", encoding="UTF-8")
> example <- xmlRoot(ex)
> xpathSApply(example, "//DOCFULL/*/*/span[text()='SECTION: ']/..", xmlValue)
NULL
```

How can I fix this expression to extract the load-dates or - even better - the actual dates of each document?

And would it be possible to have the epxression account for documents with missing dates (i.e. marking them with NA instead)?

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the DOCFULL/* and simplify the xpath...

```
xpathSApply(example, "//span[text()='SECTION: ']/..", xmlValue)
[1] "SECTION: A; Pg. 1" "SECTION: A; Pg. 1"
xpathSApply(example, "//div[@class='c3']/p[@class='c1']/span[@class='c2'][1]", xmlValue)
[1] "August 2, 2001 Thursday" "February 8, 2004 Sunday"
```

There are many ways to add NA if a node is missing a tag - it's a common question here.